# Responsive ChartJS within a page structure

Tags: chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

As soon as I give the chartJS div flexible values such as width=100%, the graph is not animated anymore.

I tried to use things such as width=45vh but this doesn't fit my need as the chart should always fill 100% of the width of the div above it.

I also tried to add the flexible width to the div id="1" (outer div). The chart is then animating but the width is totally screwed.

In Codepen it's working with exactly the same code:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ebjvMm

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ["Standard", "Premium"],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Noahs Box',
            data: [139, 189],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(30, 56, 79, 1)',
                'rgba(30, 56, 79, 1)',
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(30, 56, 79, 1)',
                'rgba(30, 56, 79, 1)',
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        },
     {
            label: 'Amazon',
            data: [192.30, 440.55],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 153, 0, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 153, 0, 1)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 153, 0, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 153, 0, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }],
    },
    options: {
      responsive: true,
     maintainAspectRatio: false,
      legend: {
       display: true
      },
      animation: {
         duration: 7500,
        },
      title: {
   display: true,
         text: 'Comparison: Noahs Box vs. Amazon'
        },
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero:true
          }
        }]
      }
    }
});
```

```html
<div style="height:450px">
 <div style="position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;">
       <canvas id="myChart"></canvas></div></div>
```

This is the page where I have the problem: https://noahsbox.com/pages/price-comparison

As you can see I I have two graphs. The second one is working as it has a fix width.

The chart should be responsive and always take 100% of the width of the 'div id="1" class="grid__item large--one-half medium-down--one-whole right-image statistic-tile' (right side of the tile/section).

AND it should animate when loading the page and not just show up without any animation.

**Helpful links:**
https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/2958
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/responsive.html#configuration-options